# Users complained about not receiving emails from email alerts

Tags: email-alert

We have an email alert to send emails automatically to our end users and it used to be working fine. And recently users started to complain about not receiving emails.

I have examined the email alert and the logic is pretty simply and looks okay to me. I have tried that in the sandbox environment and it does work for me. I have also asked the users what have they precisely done and they said they have only just updated the records in the list view.

So I am really confused here. Why are there some users who failed to receive email alerts from time to time.

Comment: have you checked email log in Salesforce?

Comment: Have we checked the deliverability in salesforce?

Comment: @KhushbooDua Yes, it is set to be All email.

Comment: A helpful link that talks that IP can be an issue. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gzZPAAY

Comment: @Himanshu Not really. I am looking at it now. But not sure what to expect from the log?

Comment: @LanceShi 1. check for Mail Event,Retry Count,Delivery Status Notification column 2. Test email deliverability

Comment: @LanceShi  Are we able to track the issue or it is still in progress?

Comment: @KhushbooDua Still in progress. We are analysing the logs and deliverability at this point

Answer (score 1):

Putting the answer from the link in the comment for easier viewing which save clicking steps. Also this is very common problem.

---

I would run an Email Deliverability Test

**Testing Deliverability**

Available in: All Editions except Database.com

**User Permissions Needed**

To test email deliverability:
“Modify All Data”
Salesforce sends email from 54 different IP addresses. If your organization blocks any of these IP addresses, users might not receive all email sent from Salesforce.

To verify your organization can receive email from every Salesforce IP address:

```
Click Your Name | Setup | Administration Setup | Email Administration | Test Deliverability.
```

Enter your **business** email address.

Click Send. Salesforce simultaneously sends a test message from all 54 IP addresses to your business email address. Each test message specifies the IP address from which it was sent.

Check your business email account to make sure it received all 54 test messages. **(as of 6 Apr 2021, SFDC only sends 16 test messages)**
If you received less than 54 test messages, your organization's email administrator must whitelist the Salesforce IP ranges on your organization's email server.

Whitelisting an IP address allows the email server to receive email from an IP address that might otherwise be blocked. The Salesforce IP ranges are:
96.43.144.64 to 96.43.144.65
96.43.148.64 to 96.43.148.65
182.50.78.64 to 182.50.78.79
202.129.242.64 to 202.129.242.65
204.14.232.64 to 204.14.232.79
204.14.234.64 to 204.14.234.79

Note:
If your organization activates email relaying, your email administrator only needs to whitelist the IP addresses Salesforce uses for email relaying (96.43.144.65, 96.43.148.65, 182.50.78.65, 202.129.242.65, 204.14.232.65, and 204.14.234.65).

For information on email relaying, see Setting Up Email Relaying.